# Vector4 crossproduct

Tags: c++, vector

I'm working on finishing a function in some code, and I've working on the following function, which I believe should return the cross product from a 4 degree vector.

```
Vector3 Vector4::Cross(const Vector4& other) const {
    // TODO
    return Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)
}
```

I'm just not sure of how to go about finding the cross product for a 4 degree vector.

Comment: Cross product only makes sense in three dimensions. Are you using projective coordinates or something? If so, you should specify

Comment: I'm passing in a 4-degree vector (x, y, z, w). Should I just ignore the w and use x, y, and z to calculate a cross product?

Comment: If it's a vector in homogenous coordinates, you divide the other components by w. So the 3-component vector you use to calculate the cross product is (x/w, y/w, z/w).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find the cross product of the x, y and z components, convert it to a `3D-Vector` and the do the normal cross product, because a cross-product for `4D-Vector`s isn't defined in general.

Comment: But the thing is I'm passing in a 4-degree vector (x, y, z, w). Should I just ignore the w and use x, y, and z to calculate a cross product?

Comment: It depends, but if you're just representing 3D points with a 4 point vector, ignore w.